# How can I save an interaction with a command line program to a file?

Tags: command-line, command-prompt, io-redirection

I need to create output files that include the input I'm providing. For example, a run of the program might look like:

```
Input command: do_things
Things have been done.
Input command: stop_doing_things
Things are no longer being done.
```

Where "do_things" and "stop_doing_things" are input from the user.

How can I output all of the above to a file using command prompt functions?

Comment: as i understood you are looking for way to capture commandpromt output to text file right?

Comment: I don't have access to the program's code.

Comment: I need to capture commandprompt input at the same time as output.

Comment: Spend some time and improve your question, with examples of what you need to do, what you have tried, and how it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what environment using "script " command linux will open a new shell and save everything done it to

Comment: Is there a windows version of this? If not I'll just port my code to linux

Answer (score 0):

This works for you, if you run it at last...

```
CMD > D:\mycmdout.txt
```

Comment: That will only capture the output of the program. I also want to capture the input

Answer (score 0):

In that case, maybe you can capture your input as a variable.  Echo the variable into the >> mycmdout.txt, then procede with the actual commands, again piped into >> mycmdout.txt as Sunny suggested.

```
SET /P variable=EnterInputHere
echo %variable% >> mycmdout.txt
```

EDIT: Be sure to use double >> as to append result to file.